# NSTextField auto increase width when not editable

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, width, nstextfield

I am making a mac osx app using Xcode/cocoa. In this app, there is a NSTextField which displays a text when a button is pressed. When the textfield is in editable behavior everything works fine, but this textfield should not be editable. The problem is that when the text is too long to be full displayed in the textfield and the textfield is not editable, the width is automatically enlarged to fit the text. What I should do to the textfield dont resize even in disabled or selectable behavior?

Comment: Not clear about your problem. I've not seen the automatically enlarged UITextField. Could you explain on this?

Comment: This enlargement just happen when the textfield is disabled os just selectable. This happen on mac OSX cocoa app, I don't know if this also happen in iOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What I should do to the textfield dont resize even in disabled or selectable behavior?"
This behavior is given by Apple itself... you can change its behavior but **it will go against the UI guidelines** of Apple. So I would say please stick to the default behavior. 
Or for learning process you can override the NSTextField and implement  AutoLayoutSizing's methods. 
Also you can do it with Constraints provided in if-else.